# Tomcat 7 Datasource injection mechanism

Tags: java, servlets, tomcat7, web.xml

I am trying to create simple web-app. And stuck on datasource injection. There seems to be several problems. So I will start from my confusion. As I understand there's 2( at least) ways to inject the DataSource into Servlet:

- web.xml
- @Resource

**web.xml** sample

```
<resource-ref>
    <res-ref-name>jdbc/MyDB</res-ref-name>
    <res-type>javax.sql.DataSource</res-type>
    <res-auth>Container</res-auth>
    <injection-target>
        <injection-target-class>ua.test.TestServlet</injection-target-class>
        <injection-target-name>dataSource</injection-target-name>
    </injection-target>
</resource-ref>
```

**@Resource** sample

```
public class TestServlet extends HttpServlet{
    @Resource
    private DataSource dataSource;
    @Override
    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp) throws     ServletException, IOException {
```

My confusion : `web.xml` doesn't work in Tomcat 7 on my simple project. In my opinion, `web.xml` option should work since there were no annotations before Java 5. Please explain.

***Update:***

**Datasource configuration**

```
<Resource name="jdbc/MyDB" 
          type="javax.sql.DataSource" 
          auth="Container"
          username="SA"
          password=""
          driverClassName="org.hsqldb.jdbcDriver"        
          url="jdbc:hsqldb:file:~/database/my_db" 
/>
```

Comment: Is your web.xml stating that you're using servlet 3.0?

Comment: Using a datasource in a servlet is Bad Practise™. Create at least a DAO. Personally, I use a Controller->Service->DAO approach. It enhances readability, maintainability and modularity of your code.

Comment: @MarkusWMahlberg my question is about technology, not practice. I just want to know why it doesn't work. And, if it will make you feel better, I do have DAO layer in other applications. :-)

Comment: Please add the Tomcat datasource configuration.

Comment: What version of Tomcat 7 are you using?

Comment: Do you have the hsqldb database jar in your Tomcat "lib" directory?

Comment: @davidfmatheson 7.0.54

Comment: @SteveC Yep, I have it in `lib`

Answer (score 6):

Try taking out the `injection-target` entry in `web.xml` and using the `name` attribute on  the `@Resource` annotation:

```
public class TestServlet extends HttpServlet {
    @Resource(name = "jdbc/MyDB")
    private DataSource dataSource;

    @Override
    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp) throws     ServletException, IOException {
    }
}
```

That worked in my local testing with Tomcat 7.0.50.  If you're looking for the annotation-less way of doing it, I haven't gotten that to work, even though it should given their changelog[1](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/changelog.html).

EDIT

I still haven't found a solution, but I was curious why this doesn't work so I took a look at the `injection-target` code.  I found that it loads the `context.xml` entry first, and does pick up the settings from `web.xml`, but chooses not to override the configuration it found in `context.xml` because it already sees a `jdbc/MyDB` entry.  I'm not sure how to get the `injection-target` settings into `context.xml` or the DB settings like `driverClassName` into `web.xml`.

Comment: Thank you! But I know, that works :-). And question is about why <injection-target> does not work.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, tomcat is a nice servlet container, but it is not a full Java EE container. From [The BalusC Code: How to install CDI in Tomcat?](http://balusc.blogspot.com/2013/10/how-to-install-cdi-in-tomcat.html), I think that out of the box tomcat is not able to do any dependency injection. Tomcat alone works perfectly associated with Spring, because it is lightweight.

If you do not want to use Spring, the link I wrote above should give you some ways to do CDI with tomcat ([TomEE](http://tomee.apache.org/) instead of tomcat, [Weld](http://weld.cdi-spec.org/) or [OpenWebBeans](http://openwebbeans.apache.org/)).

EDIT:

Apparently, recent versions of tomcat 7 should accept DI - see below the link in comment from davidfmatheson.

Comment: There's no need for Tomcat to be full JEE container to support DI into managed classes. I can say even more: two month ago I tried DI in both described ways with Jetty. And as I remember both ways worked. Besides that my web-app is so simple that it's just not logical to involve any additional framework for DI.

Comment: @AleksandrKravets What I said was just that any JEE container **must** support DI. But I also read the tomcat doc and couldn't find a line about DI. Apparently tomcat developpers made the choice not to implement it.

Comment: @SergeBallesta Not true, see the changelog for Tomcat 7: http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/changelog.html.  They seem to support exactly what the OP is trying to do (search for "injection-target").

Comment: @davidfmatheson Right, I think my tomcat version is a bit old, but with such a number of lines in tomcat7.0 changelog, it does not seem to be fully stabilized.

Comment: What is asked here is not DI but RI, which is supported for servlet 3.0.  A full EE container is not needed.