# Cannot connect to datasource using @Resource DI in Tomcat 8

Tags: java, jsp, tomcat, jakarta-ee, dependency-injection

I want to print a count of all the rows in a table on a JSP page. Something of this sort:

```
Total Products: 102
```

However I am getting `NullPointerException` while trying to obtain a connection from the datasource.

Is @Resource dependency injection supported in Tomcat 8?

In some of the online blogs it looks it is supported and working. Links below.
https://www.mkyong.com/tomcat/how-to-configure-mysql-datasource-in-tomcat-6/

**Exception:**

```
Stacktrace:] with root cause
 java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.study.crud.dao.jdbc.impl.ProductDao.getProducts(ProductDao.java:31)
    at org.apache.jsp.jsp.home_jsp._jspService(home_jsp.java:135)
    at org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:70)
```

**META-INF/context.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Context path="/product-manager-mvc1-webapp">
    <!-- PostgreSQL Datasource -->
    <Resource auth="Container" driverClassName="org.postgresql.Driver" factory="org.apache.tomcat.dbcp.dbcp2.BasicDataSourceFactory" maxActive="50" maxIdle="10" maxWait="-1" name="jdbc/product-db-v1" password="def" type="javax.sql.DataSource" url="jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/product-db-v1" username="abc"/>
</Context>
```

**ProductDao.java**

```
public class ProductDao {

    @Resource(name = "jdbc/product-db-v1")
    private DataSource dataSource;

    public ProductDao() {
    }

    public List<Product> getProducts() throws SQLException {
        List<Product> products = QueryExecutor.getAllProducts(dataSource.getConnection());
        return products;
    }

}
```

**home.jsp**

```
<%
    ProductDao productDao = new ProductDao();
    List<Product> products = productDao.getProducts();
    LOG.debug("products = " + products);
    int productCnt = 0;
    if (products != null) {
        productCnt = products.size();
    }
%>

<body>
    <h1>Resource Injection Demo</h1>
    <h3>Product Count: <%= productCnt%></h3>
</body>
```

Comment: Same problem described here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24040291/tomcat-7-datasource-injection-mechanism. I think the problem is that Tomcat is not a full fledged enterprise container. Usage of JBoss/Weblogic/TomEE will solve the problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Tomcat 8 certainly supports the injection of DataSource objects using the @Resource annotation.

It's not working for you because you're creating a`ProductDao` using the `new` operator. Injection only happens when the container controls the lifecycle of the containing object.

In the Tomcat case, this means you can perform @Resource injection into servlets, listeners, filters, etc. Tomcat does not know how to inject a ProductDao because as someone else mentioned, you need a complete Java EE server implementation for that (or use the Spring Framework).

If this is a learning exercise then you could gain a lot from trying this in one of the open source Java EE implementations such as GlassFish, Apache TomEE or WildFly (aka JBoss), where you will be able to inject your ProductDao into a servlet that would load the data and subsequently forward to your JSP.